# Can I write "A and B are the average number of apples for each boy and each girl, respectively"?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

There are some boys and some girls. I gives apples to them. 
Now, `A` represents the average number of apples for each boy.
`B` represents the average number of apples for each girl.

Can I write:

> A and B are the average number of apples for each boy and each girl, respectively.

Or, do you have better sentences?

Comment: Everyday English is the pits when it comes to explaining the statistical distribution(s) of things. I'd probably go with 'A and B correspond to the average number of apples per boy and per girl, respectively.' It's a case of choosing which you think is the lesser evil and of where the focus needs to be. Putting this in the context of a whole paragraph would help. However you do it, if you have an average, you really should identify what the average is being taken over using *per* unless it is 100% unambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "numbers" should be pluralised, and I would't include the second "each".

> A and B are the average **numbers** of apples for each boy and girl, respectively.

---

**Update:**

"Numbers" refers to "A and B", which are two seperate things. Saying "A and B are the number..." wouldn't make sense unless A and B were always the same number.

Using the word "each" before "girl" is fine, it just sounds rather repetitive. There is a lot of ambiguity when using one adjective to describe multiple nouns ([this was the best source I could find](http://theeditorsblog.net/2015/08/08/one-adjective-paired-with-multiple-nouns-a-readers-question/)), but it is very clear in this situation that the "each" describes both "boy" and "girl" as "average numbers of apples for girl" doesn't make sense.

Comment: why don't you remove the second each? Could you explain this and give some examples? I appreciate it if you can also give some reference.

Comment: "*Average numbers of apples for girl* doesn't make sense." True, but not for that reason. *Average numbers of apples for each girl* doesn't either. You have to use *per* (without each) here, not *for*. The averages don't apply to each boy and each girl. They only apply to the set of boys and the set of girls.

Comment: why does "for each" not make sense? It is the definition of the word "per".